# How to set Wallpaper of currently image on ViewPager of nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Tags: java, android, image, gridview, universal-image-loader

I am using nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. I want to to be able to see the currently image showing on ViewPaper as the phone Wallpaper. On a button click of action bar.

I have try to use :

```
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
wManager.setBitmap(loadedImage);
}
```

But the problem is that this function `onLoadingComplete` load the image from onclick of gridView Plus another 5 image. So The wallpaper is ramdom.

I just want to set the Wallpaper of the currently image showing in the ViewPager.

```
public class ImagePagerFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public static final int INDEX = 2;

    String[] imageUrls = Constants.IMAGES;

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_image_pager, container, false);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        pager.setCurrentItem(getArguments().getInt(Constants.Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0));
        return rootView;
    }

    private class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        ImageAdapter() {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```